# Does glue move?

Tags: experimental-physics

Today I accidentally put glue in a plastic tube. After a few minutes it started moving/expanding our of the tube. Why did this happen? Is it to do with the chemical makeup of the glue or something else?

Comment: What kind of glue and what kind of tube? Did the air warm up in the tube and push the glue out?

Comment: It was a pritt stick and the glue and air were at room temperature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glue is a polymer which hardens when water molecules are washed off or evaporated leading to *mechanical adhesion* but when in a plastic tube air supply is not enough hence the clue doesn't dehydrate and behaves like anyother fluid and flows .

PS : have you ever thought why does the glue not stick to it's own container?

Comment: So it flowed out of the tube?

Comment: It increases it's surface area thus to increase rate of evaporation and thus hardens . According to me. An alternate explanation might be from the surface tension and adhesive and cohesive forces.